# javascript for clicking on a link doesn't work, but works after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an html page, in the head I refer to the js file

```
<head>
   <script src="/queue.js"></script>
</head>
```

and in the body I have a link

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_ajax()">click me</a>
```

the js file is as follows (using jQuery)

```
function get_ajax(){
    $.get("/queue/get_ajax", function(data){
       $("#div_id").html(data);
    });
}
```

clicking on the link doesn't trigger the js function, but reloading the page makes it working.

Is the problem caused by the way I refer to the js file?

It is a page of a rails 4 application.

the full head is like

```
 <head> 
<title>XXXX</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
    <script src="/queue.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

and I've found the resulting html page doesn't have `<script src="/queue.js"></script>` included, when I inspect the page source code in browser

Comment: are you add jquery library on head?

Comment: yes, it's a jquery mobile webpage

Comment: Could it be caused by the caching of rails?

Comment: I've put alert(1). still nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Change the order of your js files (library first)

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/queue.js"></script>
```

Then

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="get_ajax()">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the:

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_ajax()">click me</a>
```

Use this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="get_ajax()">click me</a>
```

javascript:void(0) will stop to reload the page.

Comment: no, I tried and this doesn't work. the page is not reloaded when I click on the link.

Comment: @Tao yes this is used to prevent the page reload and will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent page from reloading you could also do this  :

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_ajax(event)">click me</a>
```

```js
function get_ajax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("/queue/get_ajax", function(data){
        $("#div_id").html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: no, the page doesn't reload when I click the link. I reload the page myself, and then the `<script src="/queue.js"></script>` part is included in the source code

Comment: I've put alert(1). still nothing happened when I click the button

Comment: one warining: event.returnValue is depracated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43984/discussion-between-tao-and-wared)

Answer (score 0):

You're including your js file which uses jquery BEFORE you include jquery. So the page doesn't know what you're "talking about" when parsing queue.js.

Include jquery first then queue.js, it should do the trick.

Comment: no, it is not due to the order. I have tried putting my js file before and after the jquery file, and got the same result.